# How to add class onto a div in page2 when onclick event is trigged on page1?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

Index page has this

```
<a href="about.html#collapseOne">Link to About page Panel 1</a>
<a href="about.html#collapseTwo">Link to About page Panel 2</a>
<a href="about.html#collapseThree">Link to About page Panel 3</a>
```

When "Link to About page Panel 1 or 2 or 3" is clicked (the index page will close) and about page will open with respective accordion panel opened.

JSfiddle for the about page as below.

https://jsfiddle.net/Deepika_Rao_PK/nv79rs8b/#&togetherjs=lx2xS3u3Ak

Found the solution: 
[sessionStorage.setItem not working in firefox / cannot pass id of div from page1 onto page2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35286436/sessionstorage-setitem-not-working-in-firefox-cannot-pass-id-of-div-from-page1)

Comment: other page means that you can look at only one at a time?

Comment: or they are part of single page?

Comment: You can do `$("#container").load("about.html #collapseOne");`

Comment: Different pages and only one will open at a time. Modified the question

Answer (score 0):

If you have two different pages. 
You can check for hash in url as below.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  if(window.location.hash =='#collapseOne') {
    $('#collapseOne').addClass('in');
  }
});
```

Comment: Modified the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS `:target`

CSS

```
.target {
    display: none;
}

.target:target {
    display: block;
}
```

HTML

```
<!-- index page -->
<a href="about.html#collapseOne">Link to About page Panel 1</a>
<a href="about.html#collapseTwo">Link to About page Panel 2</a>
<a href="about.html#collapseThree">Link to About page Panel 3</a>

<!-- page 1  -->
<div class="target" id="collapseOne">

  This content will show when hash is #collapseOne

</div>

<!-- page 2  -->
<div class="target" id="collapseTwo">

  This content will show when hash is #collapseTwo

</div>

<!-- page 3  -->
<div class="target" id="collapseThree">

  This content will show when hash is #collapseThree

</div>
```